# Is there a way to translate dates in a language selected using ngx-translate or with date-pipe?

Tags: angular, translation, ngx-translate, date-pipe

I am using angular 7 and ngx-translate for internalization purpose /multilingual support ,it worked fine static html texts tags but have found nothing on how to translate dates in a dynamic stream of data.

Have tried changing the locale of the date-pipe,but didn't worked in my case.

[Code used in html including the date pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWlE2.png)

date text and format should be changed according country selected.

Comment: Checkout date-fns: https://date-fns.org/

Comment: checked it out but they are also dependent on changing locales and importing locales dynamically is not working for me.